# Javascript attributes for select option

Tags: javascript, html

I need some assistance with the code below, I want to set what has been chosen to the textarea but I dont want to equate/return the value attribute but the narration. for the case below the textarea is getting value **1** and I want it to get the narration **Line One**

```js
var myOption = document.getElementById('priority1');
var myStrategy = document.getElementById('strategy1');
myStrategy.onchange = function () {
  myOption.value = this.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="priority1" name="priority1"></textarea>
<select id="strategy1" name="strategy1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Line one</option>
  <option value="2">Line Two</option>
  <option value="3">Line Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find the `selectedIndex`'s `option`'s text content (or HTML Content).

```html
<textarea id="priority1" name="priority1"></textarea>
<select id="strategy1" name="strategy1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Line one</option>
  <option value="2">Line Two</option>
  <option value="3">Line Three</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myOption = document.getElementById('priority1');
  var myStrategy = document.getElementById('strategy1');
  myStrategy.onchange = function() {
    myOption.value = this.querySelectorAll('option')[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the selected option by index `this.options[this.selectedIndex]` then get the option text using `.text` instead of value :

```
myStrategy.onchange = function () {
    myOption.value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
}
```

Hoep this helps.

```js
var myOption = document.getElementById('priority1');
var myStrategy = document.getElementById('strategy1');

myStrategy.onchange = function () {
  myOption.value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
}
```

```html
<select id="strategy1" name="strategy1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Line one</option>
    <option value="2">Line Two</option>
    <option value="3">Line Three</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<textarea id="priority1" name="priority1"></textarea>
```

Comment: Eh, are you sure? But this is not cross-browser safe.

Comment: Mate, what you have written at first is wrong. Giving `.textContent` will give you all the three options' values.

Comment: `textContent` isn't available in IE.

Comment: Er... When I say IE, not the latest and greatest IE 9. I would definitely say IE 7 or 8. `:)`

Comment: This is not working right, if you test it it returns all the options instead of the selected. try it you will see.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `value` of each option

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <title>Testing Code</title>
</head>
<textarea id="priority1" name="priority1"></textarea>
<select id="strategy1" name="strategy1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Line one">Line one</option>
    <option value="Line two">Line Two</option>
    <option value="Line three">Line Three</option>
</select>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var myOption = document.getElementById('priority1');
    var myStrategy = document.getElementById('strategy1');
    myStrategy.onchange = function () {
        myOption.value = this.value;
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```